# add rows header while data binding ( with DataSource property ) to datagridview

Tags: .net, datagridview, dataset, c++-cli, datasource

I create a data table with rows and columns and add it to a dataset. Finally I bind the dataset to my datagridview. My problem is: How can I add rows header?

Here is my code:

```
DataTable^  table = gcnew DataTable("Parent");
DataColumn^  col;
DataRow^  row;
for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
    Experiment^  exp = (Experiment^)my_exp_array[i];
    col = gcnew DataColumn;
    col->DataType = System::Type::GetType("System.String");
    col->ColumnName = exp->getName();
    table->Columns->Add(col);
}

for( int i = 0; i < 40000; i++ )
{
    for( int j = 0; j < 5; j++ )
    {
        Experiment^  exp = (Experiment^) my_exp_array[j];
        row = table->NewRow();
        row[exp->getName()] = exp->getValue();
    }
    table->Rows->Add(row);
}
this->dataset->Tables->Add(table);
this->datagridview->DataSource = this->dataset->Tables[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help.

```
col->Caption = exp->getName();
```

Comment: It did not change the result, finally I added all row headers manually.